# Installing Phusion Passenger on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, httpd, passenger

I've been scratching my head over this one all day. I'm basically trying to replicate I setup I have on my desktop running 10.11 (Yosemite) where I can run Rails apps on Vhosts in a local environment using passenger.

So on the new machine (laptop), I'm running macOS Sierra (10.12.2), I've set up vhosts and apache as normal and have installed passenger via homebrew.

Now when I run `sudo apachectl -t` I get:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 539 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /private/etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/apr/libexec/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library version: mod_passenger.so requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libapr-1.0.dylib provides version 5.0.0
```

I have run `xcode-select --install` so that should be fine. Command line tools version is Xcode 8.2.1.

`brew info passenger` gives me:

```
passenger: stable 5.1.1 (bottled), HEAD
Server for Ruby, Python, and Node.js apps via Apache/NGINX
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/
/usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.1.1 (3,738 files, 149.5M) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-01-09 at 16:05:11
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/passenger.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: pcre ✔, openssl ✔, apr-util ✔
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.7 ✔
==> Options
--without-apache2-module
    Disable Apache2 module
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To activate Phusion Passenger for Nginx, run:
  brew install nginx --with-passenger

To activate Phusion Passenger for Apache, create /etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf:
  LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Output of `apxs -q | fgrep -i config`

```
APR_CONFIG=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config
APU_CONFIG=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apu-1-config
ENABLED_DSO_MODULES=,authn_file,authn_core,authz_host,authz_groupfile,authz_user,authz_core,access_compat,auth_basic,reqtimeout,filter,mime,log_config,env,headers,setenvif,version,slotmem_shm,unixd,status,autoindex,dir,alias
```

Which looks good. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add the output of `apxs -q | fgrep -i config`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output of that statement to the question.

Comment: Ok so does `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config` exist? It doesn't on my machine, and I had to install apr and apr-util from homebrew and force link them.

Comment: Yeah I symlinked them earlier in an attempt to fix this issue. APR_CONFIG links to /usr/local/Cellar/apr/1.5.2_3/libexec/bin/apr-1-config and APU_CONFIG leads to /usr/local/Cellar/apr-util/1.5.4_4/libexec/bin/ Both of those files exist (would have been installed by homebrew)

Comment: Hmm I created  the links via homebrew (`brew link apr --force`) not manually, I wonder if that makes the difference?

Comment: Hmm, I'll get rid of the ones I have and try that.

Comment: Now I get: apxs:Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config not found!.
APU_CONFIG=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apu-1-config
ENABLED_DSO_MODULES=,authn_file,authn_core,authz_host,authz_groupfile,authz_user,authz_core,access_compat,auth_basic,reqtimeout,filter,mime,log_config,env,headers,setenvif,version,slotmem_shm,unixd,status,autoindex,dir,alias
APR_CONFIG=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.12.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin/apr-1-config

Comment: Yeah that looks like what I get when I run `apxs -q | fgrep -i config`. But despite the error there, Passenger + Apache does work for me in this configuration.